# how to get the total selected days from 2 calendars in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

just like in my questions, i have 2 calendars to be selected by users, and i would like to get the **total selected days** and be **displayed in label**.

users have to select the start date in lstartdate calendar and end date in lenddate calendar.

```
    private void ValidateDate()
{
    if (lstartdate.Text == "" || lenddate.Text == "")
    {
        lwarndate.Visible = true;
        lwarndate.Text = "Dates required";
    }

    if (lstartdate.Text != "" || lenddate.Text != "")
    {
        if (cstart.SelectedDate > cend.SelectedDate)
        {
            lwarndate.Visible = true;
            lwarndate.Text = "Start date must be earlier than end date!";
        }
        if (cstart.SelectedDate <= cend.SelectedDate)
        {
            lwarndate.Visible = false;
        }
        if (cend.SelectedDate != null && cstart.SelectedDate != null)
        {
            Double Value;
            if (cend.SelectedDate >= cstart.SelectedDate)
                Value = (cend.SelectedDate - cstart.SelectedDate).TotalDays;
            else
                Value = (cend.SelectedDate - cstart.SelectedDate).TotalDays;
            total.Text = // ?
        }
    }
}
```

im not sure if the code arrangements are correct or not. do help and tq :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY LIKE THIS

```
        DateTime DtF = ceFromDate.SelectedDate.Value;
        DateTime D1T = ceToDate.SelectedDate.Value;

        double dd = (DtF - D1T).TotalDays;

        total.Text = dd.ToString();
```

Comment: question, if the user only select 1 day example 16/09 till 16/09. but the output total.text is 0 days applied. it supposed to be 1 days applied. where can i add the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple way to get different between two dates

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.DateTime dtTodayNoon = new System.DateTime(2006, 9, 13, 12, 0, 0);
            System.DateTime dtTodayMidnight = new System.DateTime(2006, 9, 13, 0, 0, 0);
            System.TimeSpan diffResult = dtTodayNoon.Subtract(dtYestMidnight);
            Console.WriteLine("Yesterday Midnight - Today Noon = " + diffResult.Days);
            Console.WriteLine("Yesterday Midnight - Today Noon = " + diffResult.TotalDays);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

[Source](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/DateDiff_CS_DC09132006172429PM/DateDiff_CS_DC.aspx)

you need to implement it yourself..

Answer (score 0):

Convert the difference between the two dates into a TimeSpan, then get the amount of Days of that TimeSpan and set this as your text-value.

```cs
private void ValidateDate()
{
    if (lstartdate.Text == "" || lenddate.Text == "")
    {
        lwarndate.Visible = true;
        lwarndate.Text = "Dates required";
    }

    if (lstartdate.Text != "" || lenddate.Text != "")
    {
        if (cstart.SelectedDate > cend.SelectedDate)
        {
            lwarndate.Visible = true;
            lwarndate.Text = "Start date must be earlier than end date!";
        }else{
            lwarndate.Visible = false;
        }
        if (cend.SelectedDate != null && cstart.SelectedDate != null)
        {
            TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(cend.SelectedDate ).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(cstart.SelectedDate ));
            total.Text = duration.Days.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to write  total.Text = duration.Days.ToString();

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments. Error 2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar' to 'string'. Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments. Error 4 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar' to 'string'.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know what those values where. They are WebControls.Calendars so you will have to get the Values of the selection then. Updated post.

Comment: sorry i dont know how.